# what code can parse div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a code like that

```
<div id="product_images_54695_update" class="image-border float-left center cm-reload-54695">
<div class="cm-image-wrap"> 
    <span id="box_det_img_link_54695526fb066709b3_17149" class=" larger-image-wrap center">
        <a id="det_img_link_54695526fb066709b3_17149" class="cm-image-previewer cm-previewer" title="" href="/images/detailed/17/p54695_6768912_fotoapparat_olympus_pen_e_pm2_14_42_mm_kit_flash_a.jpg" rev="preview[product_images_54695526fb066709b3]" rel="preview[product_images_54695526fb066709b3]">
            <img id="det_img_54695526fb066709b3_17149" class=" " border="0" width="200" height="200" title="" alt="" src="/images/thumbnails/17/200/200/p54695_6768912_fotoapparat_olympus_pen_e_pm2_14_42_mm_kit_flash_a.jpg">
        </a>
    </span> 
</div>
```

i want to take in js this line as a text:

```
<img id="det_img_54695526fb066709b3_17149" class=" " border="0" width="200" height="200" title="" alt="" src="/images/thumbnails/17/200/200/p54695_6768912_fotoapparat_olympus_pen_e_pm2_14_42_mm_kit_flash_a.jpg">
```

Can i do that with jquery or native javascript?

Comment: `$('#det_img_54695526fb066709b3_17149')`

Comment: You already asked this question a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659417/which-function-to-use-for-getting-a-pictur

Comment: I don't see why you would want the line of HTML clientside. Could you show what you're planning to do?

Comment: This does smell of X/Y Problem.

Answer (score 2):

If that is content in the DOM, then select by ID, and use `.outerHTML`.

```
document.getElementById("det_img_54695526fb066709b3_17149").outerHTML;
```

---

Or select its parent and use `.innerHTML`. This assumes the parent has only the one child.

```
document.getElementById("det_img_link_54695526fb066709b3_17149").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know the `id` of the img, then you can do this:

```
$('<div/>').append($('#det_img_54695526fb066709b3_17149').clone()).html();
```

... otherwise, you can try using the `.cm-image-wrap` class further up:

```
$('<div/>').append($('.cm-image-wrap img').clone()).html();
```

Comment: The `img` element contains no HTML, so this will return an empty string.

Comment: Thanks, just noticed and corrected that :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
$("#det_img_link_54695526fb066709b3_17149").html();
```